# How to use redux to only get back a value without managing state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using the dispatch method of redux to do side effects and then get back a value. I'm not interested in managing state in this case. How can I get back a value from dispatch function?

My code in component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        const a = dispatch(
            expensesActions.getExpenseList()
        )
        console.log("return value", a)
    } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message)
    }
  }, [dispatch]);
```

I'm trying to use a for the return value but upon console.log this is what I get:

```
Promise {
  "_40": 0,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": null,
}
```

And my very simple code in my action:

```
export const getExpenseList = () => {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        return "HELLO"
    }
}
```

I want to get back the value "HELLO" where I dispatch it, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch is asynchronous, so you're console logging before you get a response. You can try:

```
dispatch(
    expensesActions.getExpenseList()
).then(result => {
    // do stuff
    console.log(result)
})
```

or

```
console.log(dispatch(expensesActions.getExpenseList()))
```